# Downloading PDF File always damaged

Tags: php, pdf

i want to create a download pdf file, but its always damaged
i had try this code in other function its working correctly but in this function the downloaded file is corrupt
source and downloaded file has same size its 3.899

this is my code before :

```
if (file_exists($dir)) {
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($dir).'"');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dir));
                readfile($dir);
                exit;
            }
```

and i had try this code too for this issue :

```
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . $length);
                set_time_limit(0);
                readfile($file);
                exit;
```

i think the problem is in file size,
my code is work corretly in size under 1Mb but i dont know how to change max download size, i had try to search in php.ini but i cant find

====> update

i had try to change file to smaller size file (below 1Mb) but its still damaged

Comment: Maybe you have some output before the  `readfile($file)` statement. Check the log files to see if an warning about *headers already sent* exists.

Comment: where i can find log file?

Comment: Try in `/var/log/apache/` under the name `errors.log` or similar

Comment: I already found the problem, the path that i used is actually right (i can download but corrupt) and then i input the path manually and its turn out okay... The corrupt file happen when i append the path with variables and this is the error i get "Use of undefined constant varName - assumed 'varName'" (im using $_Get['varName'];)

Comment: So the view of logs helped?

Comment: im not checking it... I just retrace my code...